# gruntでdotで区切られたファイル名についての仕様はどこに書いてあるのでしょう？

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs

angular-fullstackなどみているとファイル名がdotで区切られたファイルは結合されているようなのですが、 [Building the files object dynamically](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) 辺りをみてもイマイチ仕組みがわかりませんでした。  
この辺りの仕様がどのドキュメントに書いてあるのかご存じの方がいましたら教えて頂きたく…。
よろしくお願いします。

例:grunt-contrib-coffee
ソース
main.model.coffee
main.coffee

出力
main.js
main.src.coffee

Answer (score 1):

gruntの仕様としてファイルの結合がある訳ではなく、Gruntfile.jsに定義されたタスクでファイルの結合を行っている形になります。
あくまでもgruntはタスクランナーなので、ソースの変換や結合などの処理は各タスクで使用しているプラグインで行われます。
Gruntfile.jsにbuildタスクが定義されているはずなので、そちらで実行しているタスクの設定を見ていただくと、どのように結合するのかわかると思います。

https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/master/app/templates/Gruntfile.js#L812-L831
angular-fullstackでは下記のプラグインでJavascriptのビルド処理を行っているので、それぞれのREADMEを確認していただければ設定内容を読めると思います。（プロジェクト生成前のファイルなので若干の違いがあると思います）

・concat - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat
・copy - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy
・uglify - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify
・coffee - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee (coffeeは生成前のGruntfile.jsのbuildタスクにはないです)

Comment: `extDot: 'last'` を付けたら上手くいきました。ご回答ありがとうございます。

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804610/grunt-contrib-coffee-one-to-one-compile